# Help identifying the word(s?) that describe or define this description:

Tags: terminology

An *apple* **is** a *fruit*,
but a *fruit* **isn't** an *apple*.

---

This is not about the Definite and indefinite articles.

But this is about the subject of:

- We *are able* to call something like an apple a fruit.
- We *are not able* to call a fruit an apple (because not all fruits are apples.)

---

What do you call this aspect of the English language?

I remember learning about this particular Topic in either English class, or in a Grammar class.

Comment: Is the word _frtit_ intentional or did you mean fruit?

Comment: @KillingTime, I think it was a typo.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul That was my initial thought but it was in there twice.

Comment: Didn't notice the second one.

Comment: Are you speech impaired? able smable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word for "moving up one conceptual level"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205760/word-for-moving-up-one-conceptual-level) 'Fruit' is a _hypernym_ of 'apple', 'orange', 'lime' .... 'Apple' etc are _hyponyms_ of 'fruit'. Superset/set and subset/set analysis in English language  terms.

Comment: Hello 3288107, please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question about editing solved into the title.  You've already accepted the answer with the tick, which is sufficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of logic and maths, we have ***superset*** and ***subset***, but when it comes to ***language***, the more usual terms are...

> **Hyponymy** and **hypernymy** [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy_and_hypernymy)
> *a **hyponym** is in a "**type-of**" relationship with its **hypernym**.
>
> For example, pigeon, crow, eagle and seagull are all hyponyms of bird (their hypernym); which, in turn, is a hyponym of animal.*
> *Other names for **hypernym** include **umbrella term** and **blanket term**.*

---

In OP's example,...
***apple*** is a ***hyponym*** (type of) ***fruit***
***fruit*** is a ***hypernym*** of ***apple, pear, banana***, etc.

Comment: I like this answer.

Answer (score 2):

"**Coreference**" is the reference in one expression to the same referent in another expression.([ref.](https://glossary.sil.org/term/coreference), [lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/coreferential))

ref.: On Paraphrase and Coreference - MIT Press Journals

- [The two expressions in bold are coreferential, but they are also a paraphrase of one another.] *Tony went to see the **ophthalmologist** and got his eyes checked. The **eye doctor**
  told him …*
- ***Paraphrasing and coreference** are usually defined as **sameness relations**: Two expressions that have the same meaning are paraphrastic, and two expressions that refer to
  the same entity in a discourse are coreferent. The concept of sameness is usually taken
  for granted and left unexplained, but establishing sameness is not straightforward.
  A strict interpretation of the concept makes sameness relations only possible in logic
  and mathematics, whereas a sloppy interpretation makes the definition too vague.*

You can say that "fruit" and "apple" are not **coreferencial** and therefore, semantically, swapping  subject and complement is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is, apart from its English aspects, a question of *Set Theory*. There are two sets: *apples* and *fruits*.

*Apples* are entirely contained in *fruits*, and *fruits* contain more than *apples*. In set theory this is expressed by saying that *apples* are a subset of *fruits*, *fruits* are a superset of *apples*. I have heard this summarised by: the description of *apple* as  *fruit* is *complete*; but the description of *fruit* as *apple* is *incomplete*.