# Name for the previous definition to which a definite article refers

Tags: terminology, definite-articles

Pronouns refer to antecedents.

What do definite articles refer to? Are these also antecedents?

For example:

> Mary owned a fennec fox named Archibald, who was a gift from Mary's father. The fox was fearful of strangers who visited the household.

or

> Bludgeonic Corporation ("Bludgeonic") is issuing a series of 5.678% Diversified Notes (the "Notes") on August 31, 2021. The Notes are available directly from Bludgeonic.

In these examples, "The fox" refers to "a fennec fox named Archibald" owned by Mary, and "The Notes" refers to "a series of 5.678% Diversified Notes" to be issued by Bludgeonic Corporation.

Is there a name for these sentences / sentence fragments which "the <noun>" later refers to?

Comment: You could call them the "definiens" at the risk of leaving your audience puzzled.

Comment: No, they're not antecedents, because those usually come before, not after. What definite articles  are usually said to do is to determine the noun phrase they modify. There's no special name for the noun they modify. The whole noun phrase, with determiners, is said to be a [Definite Description](https://www.google.com/search?q=definite+description), and has certain properties, like uniqueness and existence.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm not talking about the noun modified by a definite article. I'm talking about a previous sentence or sentence fragment that clarifies a later use of "the <noun>".

Comment: No, you still wouldn't call them antecedents; merely coreferents.

Comment: See [help identifying the words that describe or define ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/546474/help-identifying-the-words-that-describe-or-define-this-description/546481#546481).